# ActiveAdmin: changing css file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, activeadmin

I'm confused on where to put my new css file for ActiveAdmin to use. I have a folder called public/admin/active_admin.css and here https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/261, it says to put it in active_admin.rb but this doesn't exist in my application. Where does it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to add is

```
# active_admin.rb
config.register_stylesheet 'active_admin_custom.css'
```

in the file `config/application.rb` (or an environment-specific config file) then the file /public/stylesheets/active_admin_custom.css

or you can create a new file:

`config/initializers/active_admin.rb` and put that line of code in there.

Comment: Ah that's right I forgot about the initializer folder. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. There are many ways to do the same thing in rails.

Comment: When i use this with the CSS, all the original AA CSS gets lost. any ideas?